# Using the ST monad

Tags: haskell

In the blog post, http://galvanist.com/post/83741037068/adding-badly-under-python-julia-go, the author uses a simple algorithm to compare the performance of various languages (including Haskell). In the Haskell example, the author uses a recursive function. As an exercise, I wanted to use the ST monad to allow local mutable state. This works but the recursive function is MUCH faster than my function which uses the ST monad.

Recursive function-

```
peanoAdd :: Int -> Int -> Int
peanoAdd 0 y = y
peanoAdd x y = peanoAdd (x - 1) (y + 1)

main :: IO ()
main = do
    let a = 64000000 :: Int
    let b = 64000000 :: Int
    let n = peanoAdd a b
    print n

128000000

real    0m0.583s
user    0m0.480s
sys     0m0.096s
```

Using the ST monad-

```
import Control.Monad.ST
import Data.STRef
import Control.Monad.Loops

peanoAdd :: Int -> Int -> Int
peanoAdd x y = runST $ do
    x' <- newSTRef x
    y' <- newSTRef y
    whileM_ (do x'' <- readSTRef x'
                return $ x'' /= 0)
            (do modifySTRef x' (subtract 1)
                modifySTRef y' (+1))
    readSTRef y'

main :: IO ()
main = do
    let a = 64000000 :: Int
    let b = 64000000 :: Int
    let n = peanoAdd a b
    print n

128000000

real    0m17.837s
user    0m16.412s
sys     0m1.424s
```

Is there something I am doing obviously wrong which is hurting performance in the ST monad example? (PS. I am using Stack with the simple template for both projects.)

Comment: Whenever you ask something performance related like that, you *must* provide the compiler settings etc. that you have used in your measurements.

Comment: I used `time` to measure time taken (`time stack exec ......`). I used stack to build the project. The `simple` template does not have a `ghc-options` section in the `cabal` file. However, if I add `ghc-options:  -O2` to the `cabal` files, I get essentially the same results.

Comment: Haskell is tail recursive. No ST needed in this case.

Comment: also, when timing stuff, use [Criterion](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/criterion). It's awesome.

Comment: You can expect code like the first version to be compiled (sometimes with a little coaxing) to compile to a tight loop where `x` and `y` remain in registers, whereas the `ST` should be expected to always do allocation: it's a pointer to a boxed value. And the `modify*Ref`- type functions are one of the few places where you can't expect the strictness analyzer to help you out and which should scream "space leak".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One reason your ST program could be running slow is that you're using [`modifySTRef`, which is non-strict](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Data-STRef.html#v:modifySTRef):

> Be warned that `modifySTRef` does not apply the function strictly. This
>   means if the program calls `modifySTRef` many times, but seldomly uses
>   the value, thunks will pile up in memory resulting in a space leak.
>   This is a common mistake made when using an STRef as a counter. For
>   example, the following will leak memory and likely produce a stack
>   overflow:
>
> ```
> print $ runST $ do
>     ref <- newSTRef 0
>     replicateM_ 1000000 $ modifySTRef ref (+1)
>     readSTRef ref
> ```

Your `x'` is forced once per loop, but `y'` isn't forced until the `print`, so there's a huge chain of thunks built up.

Benchmarking it on my laptop against a version using `modifySTRef'` shows how strictness can improve runtime (though both still lose to the recursive version).

```
benchmarking rec
time                 7.896 ms   (7.602 ms .. 8.269 ms)
                     0.992 R²   (0.988 R² .. 0.997 R²)
mean                 7.842 ms   (7.724 ms .. 8.001 ms)
std dev              404.5 μs   (303.9 μs .. 523.8 μs)
variance introduced by outliers: 25% (moderately inflated)

benchmarking st
time                 18.44 ms   (17.84 ms .. 19.01 ms)
                     0.996 R²   (0.993 R² .. 0.998 R²)
mean                 18.03 ms   (17.79 ms .. 18.41 ms)
std dev              750.4 μs   (528.0 μs .. 1.110 ms)
variance introduced by outliers: 16% (moderately inflated)

benchmarking st'
time                 9.191 ms   (9.028 ms .. 9.437 ms)
                     0.996 R²   (0.992 R² .. 0.999 R²)
mean                 9.317 ms   (9.175 ms .. 9.527 ms)
std dev              475.8 μs   (311.8 μs .. 677.9 μs)
variance introduced by outliers: 25% (moderately inflated)
```

The benchmarking code:

```
import Criterion.Main
import Control.Monad.ST
import Data.STRef
import Control.Monad.Loops

peanoAddST :: Int -> Int -> Int
peanoAddST x y = runST $ do
    x' <- newSTRef x
    y' <- newSTRef y
    whileM_ (do x'' <- readSTRef x'
                return $ x'' /= 0)
            (do modifySTRef x' (subtract 1)
                modifySTRef y' (+1))
    readSTRef y'

peanoAddST' :: Int -> Int -> Int
peanoAddST' x y = runST $ do
    x' <- newSTRef x
    y' <- newSTRef y
    whileM_ (do x'' <- readSTRef x'
                return $ x'' /= 0)
            (do modifySTRef' x' (subtract 1)
                modifySTRef' y' (+1))
    readSTRef y'

peanoAddRec :: Int -> Int -> Int
peanoAddRec 0 y = y
peanoAddRec x y = peanoAddRec (x - 1) (y + 1)

main =
  let n = 64000 in
  defaultMain
  [ bench "rec" $ whnf (peanoAddRec n) n
  , bench "st" $ whnf (peanoAddST n) n
  , bench "st'" $ whnf (peanoAddST' n) n
  ]
```

Comment: Ah, lazy evaluation bites again. Serves me right for not looking at the documentation. (I was instead looking at a couple of tutorials which did not use the strict version of `modifySTRef'`.) Thanks a lot!

Comment: Note that `peanoAddRec` isn't strict in `y` either, and it should be. Best to change the second pattern to `... = peanoAddRec (x - 1) $! (y + 1)`.

Comment: Also, even if you keep them evaluated with `modifySTRef'`, the contents of an STRef are always boxed, which means new `Int` objects need to get allocated on every iteration. If you want an unboxed STRef, you can try a one-element STUArray.